# How to destruct one property of a nested object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I'm working on a personal NestJS project, and I have a payload object that looks like this:

```js
payload: {
    header: [
        {
            fullName: '',
            registrationNumber: '',
            email: '',
            active: true,
            lastSeen: '',  
        }
    ]
    body: [
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        },
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        }
    ]
    footer: [
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        },
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        }
    ]
    extra: [
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        },
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        }
    ]
}
```

Every property of those objects come in an array format, and every property of it has multiples childs, every object but one: `header`.
Altough it's still inside an array, `header` there can only be one header, that's why I have an entity file that looks like this:

```js
export class ObjectEntity {
    header: HeaderObject;
    body: BodyObject[];
    footer: FooterObject[];
    extra: ExtraObject[];
}
```

I omitted some decorators with class-transformer, but the thing is, I need my entity to have all header fields declared on it alongside body, footer and extra, since those are also considered my Entity's field as well.
So it should look something like this:

```js
payload: {

    fullName: '';
    registrationNumber: '';
    email: '';
    active: true;
    lastSeen: ''; 
    body: [
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        },
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        }
    ]
    footer: [
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        },
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        }
    ]
    extra: [
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        },
        {
            field1: '',
            field2: '',
            field3: '',
            field4: '',
        }
    ]
}
```

I know I can destruct my header and create a new object with it, but I would need to do this:

```js
const {header, body, footer, extra} = payload
const newObject = {...header, body, footer, extra}
```

Is there a way for me to avoid doing it so manually? Like, is there a class-transformer decorator or something to automate this?

Comment: You can just `delete` a property from an object if you want to modify the object in place.  So, if you have `const obj = {header: headerObj, body: bodyObj};`, then you can remove a property from that object like this `delete obj.header`.

Comment: But that would not make it cleaner, would it? I would still have to do it with two consts, wouldn't I? At least to get the header part, I think...

Comment: could you provide an example payload dataset?

Comment: @EricPhillips I just edited my question with the current payload and what I need.

Comment: "*is there a class constructor decorator or something to automate this?*" - probably no, but it's unclear what this has to do with class constructors. Where is the code with `const newObject` located?

Comment: "*altough it's still inside an array, header there can only be one header*" - I suppose your `ObjectEntity` should then have `header: [HeaderObject];`? Also why is this a `class` not an `interface` if it has no methods, or did you omit some of the code?

Comment: @Bergi I misstyped, I meant to say "class-transformer method" not "class constructor", sorry!
About the other comment you've made... `header: [HeaderObject]` would it just deconstruct everything like mentioned?

And it's a class, not an interface because I indeed omitted some stuf, like some entity methods.

Comment: `header: [HeaderObject]` would accurately reflect the structure of the payload object from your first snippet. Where as the object structure in your second snippet would rather be `class ObjectEntity extends HeaderObject { body: BodyObject[]; footer: FooterObject[]; extra: ExtraObject[]; }`.